# Do governor limits changes for schedulable tasks?

Tags: governorlimits, scheduled-apex

I have a scheduled task which reads data and then sends out an email. In some cases the data returned can be very large and I am wondering if I need to make this a batch job or not.  Basically what will decide it is if the governor limits change for a scheduled task or not?

Anyone know?

Comment: Just remember that when dealing with "very large" data and sending out things like one email, a very common limit to hit is the tiny 6MB heap limit, and that only doubles to 12MB in batch. Effectively your "very large" data can never be greater than 12MB in memory at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Governor Limits don't change based on whether or not a class is scheduled, but Batch Apex does have different limits.

Here's the full Governor Limits documentation:
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_gov_limits.htm